# mySQL Data output into Two Columns

Tags: css, overflow

I am trying to output mySQL Database information into two columns

like this

Category 1 | Category 2
Category 3 | Category 4
Category 5 | Category 6
Category 7 | Category 8
Category 9 | Category 10

From left to right then downwards

i have tried various ways from css columns but cant seem to get it to work, could really do with some help

Any help would be appreciated

**thanks for the replies

the code i have at the moment is only 1 column, im pretty new at the mysql part but here it is, it would need to keep the same alphabetical order

```
<?php
```

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wss_cats WHERE parent_id = 0 ORDER BY cat_order");
$total_cats = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Num FROM wss_cats WHERE parent_id = 0"),0);
$total_cats2 = 0;

if ($setting['all_wallpapers'] == 1) {
    $url = CategoryUrl(0, 'all', 1, 'newest');

```
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.ALL_WALLPAPERS.'</a>'.$template['categories_menu_seperator'];
```

}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

```
$total_cats2 = ($total_cats2 + 1);
$seo_name = seoname($row['name']);

$url = CategoryUrl($row['id'], $row['seo_url'], 1, 'newest');

echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$row['name'].'</a>';

if($total_cats2 != $total_cats) {
    echo $template['categories_menu_seperator'];
}
```

}
?>

Comment: Post some of the code you've tried, or make a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: This a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593704/mysql-data-columns-overflow-into-a-second-row-wish-css

Answer (score 0):

you could always use tables

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Category 1</td><td> Category 2</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>Category 3</td><td> Category 3</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>Category 5</td><td> Category 5</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Except this isn't tabular data.